# How many "shares" I got, submitted, or checked by this claymore display?

Tags: mining, shares, claymore

```
ETH - Total Speed: 175.728 Mh/s, Total Shares: 2117, Rejected: 0, Time: 14:13
ETH: GPU0 29.088 Mh/s, GPU1 29.468 Mh/s, GPU2 29.079 Mh/s, GPU3 29.058 Mh/s, GPU4 29.970 Mh/s, GPU5 29.066 Mh/s
 SC - Total Speed: 3514.556 Mh/s, Total Shares: 17548, Rejected: 83
 SC: GPU0 581.755 Mh/s, GPU1 589.354 Mh/s, GPU2 581.571 Mh/s, GPU3 581.169 Mh/s, GPU4 599.390 Mh/s, GPU5 581.317 Mh/s
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:44 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 3)
 SC: Share accepted (281 ms)!
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:49 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 4)
 SC: Share accepted (656 ms)!
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:50 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 3)
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:50 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 5)
 SC: Share accepted (453 ms)!
 SC: Share accepted (1250 ms)!
GPU0 t=67C fan=71%
ETH: 05/02/17-09:24:53 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 2)
ETH: Share accepted (437 ms)!
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:55 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 2)
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:55 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 3)
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:55 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 4)
 SC: Share accepted (156 ms)!
 SC: 05/02/17-09:24:56 - SHARE FOUND - (GPU 1)


Sometimes I got "SHARE FOUND"

Sometimes I got Total Speed: 3514.556 Mh/s, Total Shares: 17548, Rejected: 83
```

What is going on?

How many shares I actually get?

Do I get a share every time I got SHARE FOUND

or do I get 17548 share once every 10 seconds or so?

The way I understand how stratum proxy works is most hash are not transmitted.

So my GPU in ETH, for example, have 29 mh/s. And most of those 29 mh every second is not even transferred to mother board at all. A few at higher difficulty is then transferred to stratum pool.

What percentage is transferred to motherboard and what percentage is transferred to stratum proxy?

And how does that effect what claymore dual miner display?

Comment: I had the same problem and a week later that GPU burned out. You should check GPU memory bus and do not overclock memory. Try to mine with stock clocks.